# In a function such that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ would the limit as $x$ approaches zero be infinity or would it not exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, rational-functions

If you have a function such as $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ , would the limit be infinity or would it not exist. A textbook I had said it was infinity but I feel like it does not exist because infinity is not a specific numeric value. So what is the limit for such an equation?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the author's persuasion.  Really, saying something like $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} = +\infty$ is just short-hand for "the limit does not exist but here's why."  The function consistently blows up from either side of $0$, so that's how you report it.  But, it definitely does not exist, even though you write it as "equal" to something.

This explains why the same author may write "$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}$ does not exist."  Here, the function exhibits different/inconsistent behavior from each side:  one blows up, one blows down.   So, you can not report that it does something consistent around $0$ regardless of side, so you have no choice but to use the words.

To answer the question in your title, the answer is unfortunately "both."  The limit does not exist *because* it approaches infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Infinity is not really a number, at least not in standard analysis.  The limit does not exist.